How to create meme coin with some conditions on solana without cli
I want to create a meme coin on solana without cli and wanna use a smart contract to develop the meme coin and implement some conditions for example , no one can own more than 1% of the liquidity pool / overall market cap.

Check out solana program examples on how to create tokens on solana program, https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/tokens/create-token which.
There are also examples on using pyth oracles too https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/oracles/pyth

Can we create  token using cli and then how can i  link conditions to that token only, e.g if a cant hold more than 1% of over supply of token. How can we do that ????

If i create a custom token using anchor and rust on solana and also the transfer function with custom condition . then will raydium use my transfer function of that token or spl ?

Or how can raydium or jupiter use my custom transfer function instead of solana spl transfer function.

I am not sure I understand your question. Yes. if you have authority over the tokens you can pretty much do anything with them.

how to override spl token transfer functio to use our custom transfer function?

I'm afraid this is a little bit too vague for me. could you create a new question for this and what you'd love to achieve?
